# Codeigniter redirect returns string instead of passing it to the url

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, codeigniter, nginx

This is my controller for login using ajax.
**Login.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {

public function index(){
    $this->load->view('login');
}

public function checkLogin(){
    if($this->input->is_ajax_request() && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])){#restrict direct access from browser
        if(empty($this->input->post('email')) || empty($this->input->post('password'))){
            echo "not";
        }else{
            if(filter_var($this->input->post('email'), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false){
                echo "not";
            }else{
                $data = array(
                        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                        'password' => md5($this->input->post('password'))
                    );
                if($this->db->select('*')&&
                $this->db->from('users')&&
                $this->db->where($data)){
                    if($this->db->count_all_results() > 0){
                        redirect('homepage'); #REDIRECT
                    }else{
                        echo "not";
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }else{
        show_error("No direct script access allowed");
    }
}
}
```

This is my javascript file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#login-form").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://citest.local/login/checkLogin',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
                email: $.trim($("#email").val()),
                password: $.trim($("#password").val())},
    })
    .done(function(result) {
        if(result == "not"){
            $(".has-feedback").addClass('has-error');
            $(".glyphicon").addClass('glyphicon-remove');
        }else{
            $(".has-feedback").removeClass('has-error');
            $(".glyphicon").removeClass('glyphicon-remove');
            $(".has-feedback").addClass('has-success');
            $(".glyphicon").addClass('glyphicon-ok');
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
});
});
```

this is the result that is returned to the console by the redirect function from my controller:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Simple Contacts</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Disable rewrite for valid directory/files     
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

#map all request urls to a specific controller method
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/{controller}/{method}/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
  # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
  # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

site config (nginx)

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /home/user/trytry/ci_test;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

# Make site accessible from http://localhost/
server_name citest.local;

# unless the request is for a valid file (image, js, css, etc.), send to bootstrap
if (!-e $request_filename)
{
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
    break;
}   

location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
    # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
}

# Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
#location /RequestDenied {
#   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;    
#}

#error_page 404 /404.html;

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
#error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#location = /50x.html {
#   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
#}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

    # With php5-cgi alone:
#   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    # With php5-fpm:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
#location ~ /\.ht {
#   deny all;
#}
}
```

Why redirect is not working as it supposed to be? It returns string instead of redirecting the url. Please help! :(

Comment: where is your homepage controller?

Comment: and what string it returns??

Comment: It returns the content of the view.

`code`
      <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <title>Simple Contacts</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    </head>
    <body>
     
    </body>
    </html>
`code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX isn't designed to work like that.  Your redirect with the code

```
redirect('homepage'); #REDIRECT
```

is redirecting your ajax request to that page, which is then getting the information from the homepage view, and then passing that back as the AJAX response.

If you want to redirect, you should pass back a success or fail message via AJAX, and then use JavaScript to redirect within the browser